# How can I crop an image in Qt?

Tags: image, qt, crop

I load a PNG image in a QPixmap/QImage and I want to crop it. Is there a function that does that in Qt, or how should I do it otherwise?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can use [QPixmap::copy](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpixmap.html#copy):

```
QRect rect(10, 20, 30, 40);
QPixmap original('image.png');
QPixmap cropped = original.copy(rect);
```

There is also [QImage::copy](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qimage.html#copy):

```
QRect rect(10, 20, 30, 40);
QImage original('image.png');
QImage cropped = original.copy(rect);
```

Answer (score 29):

Use QImage instead of QPixmap:

```
    QImage image("initial_image.jpg");
    QImage copy ;
    copy = image.copy( 0, 0, 128, 128); 
    copy.save("cropped_image.jpg");
```

This code will save a file cropped to upper left corner 128x128px.

Comment: You can use `QPixmap` to do the same operation; additionally, `QPixmap` has `toImage()` if you're starting from a `QPixmap` and want it as a `QImage`. You can do that in one line as such: `QImage copy = pixmap.copy(0,0,128,128).toImage();`

Answer (score 4):

Since you use QPixmap, you can use its [copy method](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qpixmap.html#copy) and supply it with a [QRect](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qrect.html) to perform the actual crop.

Answer (score 2):

Just use of the QPixmap's copy() functions.

This text is result of reading the first comment on your quiestion:

Sometimes it is better to wrap around an image. That is to have an image that is part of another image or in other words points to a part of another image. This is way the wrapped image does not require additional memory, except for its header. You can display or save the wrapped image without worries. The downside is that the original image must remain valid until you use the wrapped image, also if you are drawing in the wrapped image it will affect the source.